# AngularJS: Opening multiple tabs in the panel with different views for different tree nodes

Tags: jquery, angularjs, tabs

I have a requirement where we have a nav tree on the left panel and when a particular node in tree is clicked it opens up a tab in the right panel with content inside it.
By clicking various nodes one can have multiple tabs opened in right panel. Also if the tab is already there in the right panel then clicking the corresponding node should highlight/visible it and if tab is not there then a new tab should come up.

Also there are three types of nodes in the nav tree and when the different type of node is clicked it should open corresponding form inside the tab.
Kindly suggest how to achieve this. Also what are the AngularJS directives used in this whole implementation.

Also what should be the container for the multiple tabs opened?

Regards,
Faraz

Answer (score 0):

I done something similar a few months back, though I wasn't using tabs, I was just hiding or showing the correct page. I used this treeview http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview, it's very simple to use.

In my project I had one root (the company), many locations and many contacts. Contacts where assigned to a location. Clicking on the company (root) allowed the user to change the company name (or add a new one), clicking on a location displayed the location details and hid the company details and allowed the user to edit or create a new location and likewise with the contact.

Comment: Sorry missed read the question a little, thought you were after a tree view control.